# How many I2C lines does the Arduino Due have?

Tags: i2c, arduino-due

According to the [Arduino pin Mapping](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMappingSAM3X)

```
20  PB12    SDA 3   6
21  PB13    SCL 3   6
70  PA17    SDA1    3   6
71  PA18    SCL2    15  9
```

The first one seems pretty obvious, the second one though is confusing. They have different labels. I also do not see other SDA or SCL in the table. So is this a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Wire library documentation https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=132130.0:

> The Arduino Due has two I2C / TWI interfaces SDA1 and SCL1 are near to
>   the AREF pin and the additional one is on pins 20 and 21.

And the table:

Arduino Due: 20 (SDA), 21 (SCL), SDA1, SCL1

So it seems in your table SCL2 should be SCL1.

Comment: It would seem that arduino has a typo in their documentation

Comment: Fully agree on that, note that my link is also from Arduino itself, and it's contradictory with your Arduino link. Probably you can write to them about it.